# Agar Agar - trials and tribulations!

Tags: food-science

I am not one to waste anything, and happen to have a load of agar agar, but a lot of time I only want to use a small amount, and seem incapable of making such an amount - is there anyone out there who knows some great tricks here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem is exactly. Just get a precision scale with 0.1g accuracy?

Comment: Ah, well that would be a great idea, however, I don't have one, live on a boat, therefore it would not get used, and take up valuable space.  But you have given me an idea.  I will measure out what looks like a gram and then very carefully with a knife cut it into smaller percentages of a gram.  Will try this with my seafood tower a bit later on...

Comment: The precision scale I have fits into my pocket, so I imagine even on a ship you'd have room for one.